# Is there an installer that puts php, mysql and iis on a windows 2008 laptop

Tags: php, apache, iis-7, mysql-workbench

I am lookong for an easy way of installing mysql and php on my laptop.  Then I want to test running a website on the laptop using iis.  Is there an simple way to do this?

If not, is there an installer that installs php, mysql and Apache or something?

Can anyone help
Thanks
Conor

Comment: There's plenty for for php, mysql and Apache.... xampp and wamp to name the two most popular

Comment: Is it IIS or apache that you want?

Comment: http://www.appservnetwork.com/